# Admin and user login on same browser with same time in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-6

I am using laravel with default `auth(php artisan make:auth)`. I'm login as admin or user that is working well with a different time slot on the same browser. My question is when I logged in as admin and from admin want to login into the user at a new tab (the same browser From users list and click on a button). Then admin did logout automatically.

Is anyone please guide me, How to login admin into user dashboard?

Comment: Take a look at using different guards and providers for both roles: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question but, essentially logins are all sessions managed on the server side which stores this info on the browser for future communication, that is why laravel stores a 'laravel_session' cookie on the browser therefore, on the same browser same site this is passed along I guess therefore log in as a different user means altering this cookie and thus invalidating it, resulting to the above result

Comment: Thanks, @Jerodec I'm using middleware for both admin & user. Is it working if we'll use guards and providers?

Comment: Thanks, @Johhn your idea

Comment: As Johnn has stated, it's not really possible. Use an Incognito/Private window for your second session.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke, I was wondering this logic that but I'm not able to open Incognito/Private window. how to open Incognito/Private window using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Is impersonation something you are looking for (i.e. do you want that admin can check user's page(s))?

Comment: @Tpojka, Yes admin wants to login into the user dashboard and change the user's setting.

Comment: Check and study [this](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate) package.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this, which I have applied without problems, at least in laravel 7, is that the administration panel is in another subdomain, for example **admin.app.com**, while the frontend or user dashboard would run in for example, **app.com** or **account.app.com**.

Then in **config/session.php**, **'domain'** should be empty, or in the **.env** file, in **SESSION_DOMAIN** leave it empty.

This way if we log in to admin.app.com, a cookie (.env file SESSION_COOKIE) will be created with domain admin.app.com, and if we log in with an end user in app.com, the cooie will have as domain app .com, and both will be able to coexist without problems, with a session, login and independent logout.

Although defining a domain in config/session.php in 'domain', it's very useful to maintain the session between different subdomains of the application, in this particular case, leaving it empty or undefined allows solving the problem of user and administrator sessions independently coexisting in the same browser.